# Can I use 'juju backup create' with the local provider when my primary user is not 'ubuntu'?

Tags: backup, juju

Vitals: HP DL380 g5; Ubuntu 14.04.2 trusty; Juju 1.24.0-trusty-amd64; local provider.

I'm trying to back up my juju configuration using 'juju backup create', but it's failing to log in to the bootstrap machine 0:

```
$ juju backup create
DEPRECATED: Use "juju backups create" instead of "juju backup".
Connecting to machine 0
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
ERROR subprocess encountered error code 255
ERROR subprocess encountered error code 255
```

Side note: juju tells me that 'juju backup' is deprecated, and to use 'juju backups create' instead, but it doesn't recognize 'backups' as a command (gives 'ERROR unknown object type "Backups"').

The problem appears to be that machine 0 is localhost, and the user I'm running juju under is not 'ubuntu' (the user created on the other containers).  From /var/log/auth.log:

```
sshd[25294]: Invalid user ubuntu from ::1
sshd[25294]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubuntu [preauth]
sshd[25294]: Connection closed by ::1 [preauth]
```

I don't have a ubuntu user on my server - also, since [bug #1328958](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/juju-core/+bug/1328958) looked like it might be related, I checked and there is no /home/ubuntu directory, nor any entry for ubuntu in passwd.

I could probably create a ubuntu user on the server and recreate the environment under that user, but that seems a bit kludgy.

Does anyone know how I can get this working using a non-'ubuntu' user on the host, and/or whether I'm likely to run into any other issues by using juju under a username other than 'ubuntu'?